# document.write for specific time

Tags: javascript, getdate

I programmed this to display some images for a set time. it was supposed to display from Midnight on 12/2 EST to Midnight on 12/3 EST. When i checked it at Midnight on 12/2 it was working, when i checked this morning it had died. can you tell me where my error is?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 var banner = new Array();
 banner[0] = "";
 banner[1] = "";
 banner[2] = "";
 banner[3] = "";
 banner[4] = "";
 banner[5] = "";
 banner[6] = "";
 var d = new Date();
 if ((d.getUTCDate() >= 2 && d.getUTCHours() >= 5) && (d.getUTCDate() <= 4 && d.getUTCHours() <=5)) 
 {
 document.write(banner [0], banner [1], banner [6], banner [5])}  
 else
 {
 document.write(banner [6], banner [5], banner [4], banner[1])
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: It had died? What do you mean with that? And where are your actual banners? Are they empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(d.getUTCDate() >= 2 && d.getUTCHours() >= 5) refers to 12/2 5:00am to 12/3 0:00am

(d.getUTCDate() <= 4 && d.getUTCHours() <= 5) refers to 12/4 0:00am to 12/4 5:00am

12/3 0:00am to 12/4 0:00am missing,

Therefore:

```
var banner = new Array();
 banner[0] = "0";
 banner[1] = "1";
 banner[2] = "2";
 banner[3] = "3";
 banner[4] = "4";
 banner[5] = "5";
 banner[6] = "6";
 var d = new Date();
 if ((d.getUTCDate() == 3)||(d.getUTCDate() >= 2 && d.getUTCHours() >= 5) && (d.getUTCDate() <= 4 && d.getUTCHours() <=5)) 
 {
 document.write(banner [0], banner [1], banner [6], banner [5])}  
 else
 {
     alert(d.getUTCHours())
 document.write(banner [6], banner [5], banner [4], banner[1])
 }
```